# How to restore localhost mysql database after Windows reset?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mysql, database

Well I did Windows 10 Reset, after that install Apache and Mysql, how  to restore Databases ?

I reset Windows 10, following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026528/windows-10-reset-or-reinstall) article and keep files option, so all files are here, but DB is gone:

Comment: You do have a backup, right ? Sadly, even photorec cannot restore mysql database files. It can get table metadata `frm` files. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec

Comment: So I cannot restore it ? But Microsoft says "No files will be deleted" ?

Comment: Are the files there or are they NOT there, is the question ... what exactly are you referring to as a "Windows reset". Please indicate what you did to "reset" Windows, in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore mysql database using files on data folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1328965/how-to-restore-mysql-database-using-files-on-data-folder)

Comment: @user2531336 It's edit

Comment: Note that if you left the install directory for mysql as "C:\Program Files x86" the files have likely been deleted. I personally have not tested that..

Comment: *Microsoft says "No files will be deleted"* Search for old mysql data folder. If found, stop MySQL service, replace new folder with old one (save new, and make a copy of old before), then start service and check for your data. MySQL version must be absolutely the same. In common it is `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server X.X` folder.